# How to use Dynamic LINQ (System.Linq.Dynamic) for LIKE operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic-linq

Can any body tell me how can I use a LIKE operator using [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)?

I need to add more than one `LIKE` expression in my dynamic *where query*

```
/*
var query =
db.Customers.
Where("CityName Like @0 or CityName Like @1", "London", "USA")
*/
var query =
db.Customers.
Where("CityName Like @0 or CityName Like @1%", "London", "USA")
```

thanks heaps

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using simply "CityName.Contains(@1)" this will convert to the proper lambda since its a method invocation on an accessible type.

something like:

```
var query =
db.Customers.
Where("CityName.Contains(@0) or CityName.Contains(@1)", "London", "USA")
```

Just tested it with the sample app that comes with the dynamic library and it generates the LIKE operator

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.StartsWith(),` `.EndsWith()` and `.Contains()` which will generate LIKE SQL with trailing, leading and surrounding wildcards respectively. Don't know of a way to generate a statement with an embedded wildcard tho.

Answer (score 5):

This will allow the `LIKE` operator on integer fields:

```
.Where(searchField + ".ToString().Contains(@0)", searchString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add more where clauses

```
var query = db.Customers.Where(c=>c.CityName.contains("London"));
query = query.Where(c=>c.CityName.contains("USA"));
query = query.Where(c=>c.CityName.contains("Johannesburg"));
```

but the above query will create it :

> select * from Customer where CityName
>   like "london" **and** CityName like
>   "USA" etc...

you want

> select * from Customer where CityName
>   like "london" **or** CityName like
>   "USA" etc...

To use Dynamic Created or statements you can use **predicatebuilder** there's really alot
of functionality there that you can use...

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Customer>();
predicate = predicate.Or(c=>c.CityName.Contains("London"));
predicate = predicate.Or(c=>c.CityName.Contains("USA"));
predicate = predicate.Or(c=>c.CityName.Contains("Johannesburg"));
```

Comment: I need to use dynamic expression so I should pass   criterias as string

Comment: thanks Gavan and sorry for misunderstanding ,I just need to add field dynamicly to the where clause just as string 
look:
Where("CityName Like @0 or CityName Like @1", "London", "USA")
has fields in a string and can being generated dynamically but its not a case in your example .
but thanks for your company

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
IList<string> keyword = new List<string>() { "London", "USA", "Johannesburg" };
            var query = db.Customers.Where(c => keyword.Contains(c.CityName));
```

Comment: I like your trick but its not the correct answer cos I need to dynamicly select my field names from string So thanks mate.