# Dynamic library (System.Linq.Dynamic) SQL LIKE Operator

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic-linq

Someone has posted a similar question here [How Dynamic library (System.Linq.Dynamic) support LIKE Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599989/how-dynamic-library-system-linq-dynamic-support-like-operator)

But it's not exactly what I want. The **Contains** operator mentioned in that post only do this in SQL **"%SOMETHING%"**. But the **LIKE** operator in SQL can do this **"SOME%THING"**. Is there a similar operator for Dynamic LINQ? If not, is there a solution for this? Maybe with Regex? Also is there a single character wildcard? E.g. "SOM$THING" returns "SOMETHING" or "SOM3THING"

Edit: I am developing a WPF application which should read log files in XML format. Each element contains 34 fields. So instead of writing a very long WHERE, I have used System.Reflection.PropertyInfo to iterate each field to write the query and then use System.Linq.Dynamic to execute it.

Edit2: I have edited the code so it's more readable for the viewers.

Here is some code:

Example 1: 
prop.Name = "FirstName", paramterString = "Ke%in", returns "Kevin", 
"Kelvin"...
Example 2:
prop.Name = "FirstName", paramterString = "Ke$in", returns "Kevin", 
"Kelin"...

```
var query = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var prop in stringProps)
{
    sb.Append($"({prop.Name} != null And {prop.Name}.Contains({parameterString})");
}
query = sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 4);
filteredData = filteredData.Where(query);
```

One of the requirement is to implement a SQL LIKE operator, so the users can use something like this to get the result they want: FirstName LIKE 'SOME%THING'

Comment: Can you restrict your project to MS SQL Server? Then you could [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450835/2557128) Dynamic LINQ to support `SQLMethods.Like`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, because the data are imported by reading XML files.

Comment: On the post you linked, there's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600035/3002584) suggesting to use a combination of `Contains`, `StartsWits`, `EndsWith`. Can this work for you? You can also use a Regex-Like, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like). But a pure `LIKE` is something that LInq doesn't provide.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of. So I have used String.IndexOf() to create my own LIKE operator. If someone can review the code or even better, optimize it, I would be appreciate it. The code is posted in the answer.

Comment: It begins to sound like this has nothing to do with SQL. If you just want to implement a `LIKE` style operator for LINQ to Objects, I would suggest translating SQL `LIKE` patterns to RE, and using the C# Regular Expression handling.

Comment: Well, I have included the SQL tag because apparently the LIKE operator only exists in SQL or at least C# does not support it out of the box. I have looked into regular expression, but I have zero experience with RE and I don't have time to study it now. I am WAY behind schedule because of this wildcard thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no LIKE operator in Dynamic Linq library, I have created it my own version. The code is not pretty, but it does work. Hopefully someone can optimize it or suggest a better way to do this.

```
public string ParseWildcardInParameterString(string parameter, string propertyName)
{
    string stringWithWildcard = parameter;
    if (parameter.Contains("%") || parameter.Contains("$"))
    {
        stringWithWildcard = parameter;
        string[] substrings = parameter.Split(new Char[] { '%', '$' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] wildcards = ParseWildcards(parameter);
        if (substrings.Any())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int substringsCount = substrings.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < substringsCount; i++)
            {
                if (!substrings[i].EndsWith("\\"))
                {
                    int index = parameter.IndexOf(substrings[i]);
                    if (i < substringsCount - 1)
                    {
                        index = parameter.IndexOf(substrings[i + 1], index + 1);
                        if (index > -1)
                        {
                            string secondPart = wildcards[i].Equals("%") ?
                                $"{propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i + 1]}\", {propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i]}\") + \"{substrings[i]}\".Length) > -1" :
                                $"{propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i + 1]}\", {propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i]}\") + \"{substrings[i]}\".Length + 1) == {propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i]}\") + \"{substrings[i]}\".Length + 1";
                            sb.Append($"({propertyName}.IndexOf(\"{substrings[i]}\") > -1 And {secondPart}) And ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stringWithWildcard = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 5, 5).Append(") Or ").ToString();
        }
    }
    return stringWithWildcard;
}

private string[] ParseWildcards(string parameter)
{
    IList<string> wildcards = new List<string>();
    foreach (var chararcter in parameter.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (chararcter.Equals('%') || chararcter.Equals('$'))
        {
            wildcards.Add(chararcter.ToString());
        }
    }
    return wildcards.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if the **Like** functionality in [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) does work for you?

Code example would be:

`var dynamicFunctionsLike1 = context.Cars.Where(config, "DynamicFunctions.Like(Brand, \"%a%\")");`

For full example, see [ConsoleAppEF2.1.1/Program.cs](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src-console/ConsoleAppEF2.1.1/Program.cs#L1112)

Comment: I got an error "DynamicFunctions is not valid" or something.

Comment: Are you using EF 2.x ?

Comment: No, I just use standard Dynamic Linq. This code actually execute the filter.

filteredData = filteredData.Where(query, parameters.ToArray());

Comment: For that to work, you need the NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq